# CORS on One Endpoint Django

Tags: django

I am new to Django and I have 2 endpoints in a REST API:

```
api.myapp.com/PUBLIC/
api.myapp.com/PRIVATE/
```

As suggested by the names, the `/PUBLIC` endpoint is open to anyone. However, I want the `/PRIVATE` endpoint to **only accept calls** from `myapp.com` (my frontend). How can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing how you apps and servers are setup, I think you can solve this problem with the [django-cors-headers](https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers) package. I skimmed the entire read me, and the [signals](https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers#signals) at the bottom looks like a solution to your problem. This part here:

> A common use case for the signal is to *allow all origins to access a
> subset of URL's, whilst allowing a normal set of origins to access all
> URL's*. This isn't possible using just the normal configuration, but it
> can be achieved with a signal handler.
>
> First set CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS to the list of trusted origins that are
> allowed to access every URL, and then add a handler to
> check_request_enabled to allow CORS regardless of the origin for the
> unrestricted URL's. For example:
>
> ```
> # myapp/handlers.py from corsheaders.signals import check_request_enabled
>
> def cors_allow_api_to_everyone(sender, request, **kwargs):
>     return request.path.startswith('/PUBLIC/')
>
> check_request_enabled.connect(cors_allow_api_to_everyone)
> ```

So for most cases django-cors-headers are set as an option for the entire project, but there seems to be a way here for you to allow a subset of your api (`/PUBLIC` in your case) to be allowed for everyone, but the rest is private.

So your config would be

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "https://myapp.com",
]
```

That allows myapp.com to reach everything.
`cors_allow_api_to_everyone` is a function checking for a truth value.
If it is true, the request is allowed.
`check_request_enabled.connect(cors_allow_api_to_everyone)` connects your truth-check-function to the django-cors-headers signal.

Comment: I have updated my answer for the both of you. You would still have to read the docs on django-cors-headers Nick, but I highlighted the part I think is the most important for you. If you are new to [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/signals/) in django that might also be worth a read so it's not all too magic.